# Scaling Google BigQuery Extracts in an App Engine Flask app for ETL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-bigquery

Trying to deploy an ETL script which extracts data from BigQuery via Pandas-gbq and Google Sheets, and then uploads the transformed whole back to BigQuery. I want to deploy it as Flask app in App Engine.

I am using Sheets API to access Google Sheets and Pandas-gbq to access Google BigQuery. I have increased App Time out to 6000 seconds. While I get a response for a small number of rows (~100), for larger loads it boots workers with increasing PIDs and then shuts down.

I do not get an error message, and the status of the job displays Ran Successfully, however the data is not appended to the correct location as it was when the number of rows was small or if I ran it locally.

Do I need more computing power from the VM or another way to run the process? What would be the best way to deploy a bunch of such apps scheduled via a cron job to run at various times in a week?

It would be a difficult task to rewrite all the scripts, so any method to directly deploy them via app engine should help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the server in App Engine console?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I'm getting right how is your architecture. Are you using Dataflow or any other GCP service for ETL jobs? Are you not able to find any error messages in the Stackdriver logs? Could you show a code snippet of your ETL script as well as how are you executing it?